# Aftermarket stereo wired up, turns on, but no sound

Tags: audio

I have a 2004 Lexus es330 and I bought a wiring harness and aftermarket stereo. I connected all the wires red to red, black to black, yellow to yellow, and blue white stripe to blue white stripe. It turns on but there is no sound(my harness has RCA connections and those are connected properly).

The only wires that are not connected are orange, black white stripe, and blue.

Can someone help me out with this, I'd really appreciate it

Comment: What are the functions of the 3 not connected?

Comment: Does it have a pioneer amp in the glovebox ? And did you get the proper harness ? The front and rear speakers all have different colours for pos and neg connections

Comment: Are you using an input, like usb? The blue wire is for the antenna, so if your not inputting something, you probably are not getting any radio signals coming in for you to hear

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly, but have you turned up the volume?  If you have an extra speaker, try connecting it to the RCA connectors to be sure you are getting output from the stereo.